# Node module based on C++

Tags: c++, node.js, git, msbuild

I just wrote my own node module in C++ with the help of `node-gyp`. Now I have the following question.

If I want to publish my project now, what has to be in the `package.json` and can a user install my npm package if he has no Visual Studio (msbuild.exe) installed. Has he recompile it? And if yes, that doesn't really make sense. He should use the binaries only. But how can I achieve this?

Yeah, that are a lot of questions =)

FYI, here is my project: https://github.com/frankred/node-mouzy

Here is my package.json: https://github.com/frankred/node-mouzy/blob/master/package.json

Via the GIT-Repo I **only** can install the npm package with the following command:

`npm install -S "git+https://github.com/frankred/node-mouzy.git"`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-developers.html
&
https://gist.github.com/coolaj86/1318304

Comment: Sorry this does not help me!